# \citet in tabular environment

Tags: tabularray

I have a problem with the table environment when using \citet BibTeX. it did not display the citation in the last column " related literature". Any suggestions to make this long table look better?

Here are my code and output

code :

```
       \documentclass{article}
       \usepackage[margin=2cm,a4paper]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
       \usepackage{natbib}
      \usepackage{amsmath}
      \usepackage{amssymb}
      \usepackage{bbm}
      \usepackage[english]{babel}
      \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
       \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
       \usepackage{enumerate}
       \usepackage{enumitem}                    
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
         \usepackage{pdflscape}
         \usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}
         \usepackage[english]{babel}
         \usepackage{xcolor}
         \newcommand\tc[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
          \usepackage[font={bf},skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption} 
          \usepackage{longtable} 
           \usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}

      %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
       \usepackage{varioref}  
        \usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
        \usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref} 
        \crefname{equation}{eq.}{eq.}
         \usepackage{microtype}  % new
         \usepackage{tabularray}
          \UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, varwidth}



       %------------------------------% Pull factors % -------------------------------------

    \newcommand{\RealGDPpercapita}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape RGDPpercap}}\nolimits}
     \newcommand{\GDPconst}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape GDPCons }}\nolimits}
       \newcommand{\GDPgrowth}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape GDPG}}\nolimits}
       \newcommand{\realinterestrate}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape RealIRate}}\nolimits}
        \newcommand{\inflation}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape Infl}}\nolimits}
        \newcommand{\bitswithusa}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape BIT}}\nolimits}
        \newcommand{\tradeopen}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape TradeOpen}}\nolimits}
       \newcommand{\kai}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape KAI}}\nolimits}
       \newcommand{\kao}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape KAO}}\nolimits}
       \newcommand{\meanportfoliovol}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape CFV}}\nolimits}
       \newcommand{\peglag}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape Peg}}\nolimits}
        \newcommand{\kaopen}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape Capital account openness}}\nolimits}
        \newcommand{\EXR }{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape EXR}}\nolimits}

       %----------------------------------- % Push factors------------------------------------

       \newcommand{ \vix}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape vix}}\nolimits} 
      \newcommand{\MThree}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape M3}}\nolimits}
      \newcommand{\Fed}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape Fed }}\nolimits}
        \newcommand{\Shadow}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape  Shadow}}\nolimits}

      %----------------------------------- % Contagion variables-----------------------
           \newcommand{ \Trade}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape Trade linkage }}\nolimits} 

        %---------------------------------------------------------------
        \begin{document}
        %------------------------------------------------

           \begin{table}[ht]
             \setlist[itemize]{nosep, 
              wide,
              after=\end{minipage},                  % <---
              before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth} % <---
             }
     \caption{Appendix}
     \label{tab:addlabel}                                    
       \begin{tblr}{colspec={@{} Q[l, font=\bfseries] 
                      X[2,j]
                      X[j]
                 @{}},
         row{1} = {font=\bfseries, c, m},
         measure = vbox
         }
% table preamble
\toprule
    Symbol 
    &   Variable Description
    &   Source                       
            &   Related Literature                       \\
      % table body
       \midrule
      \SetCell[c=3]{c, font=\itshape}     Push factors 
      &   &                                   \\
         \midrule    
     \MThree
     & M3 for the United States, National Currency, Monthly, Seasonally Adjusted        
     &  Available at: \url{https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/MABMM301USA657S}
     & \citet{Belke2019,BIS2017} \\
    \Fed 
   & Effective Federal Funds Rate. In percentage points, end of the period, monthly.
   &IMF International Financial Statistics and Fed. Reserve Bank of St. Louis (2021b) 
  Available at: \url{https://www.federalreserve.gov/monetarypolicy.htm}
& \citet{Belke2019,BIS2017}                             \\      
\Shadow 
&US shadow rate from Federal Reserve Bank of Atlanta
& Haver Analytics 
& \citet{wu2016,liao2021}\\

        %------------------------------------------------------------------     
         \midrule
       \SetCell[c=3]{c, font=\itshape}     Pull factors
&   &                                   \\
   \midrule

  \RealGDPpercapita
  & Real GDP per capita (log)
  &  WDI 
    & \citet{liao2021,goldberg2018}.\\
    \\
    %---------------------------------------------------------------------
   \GDPgrowth
    & GDP growth (annual \%)
    &  WDI  
    &\citet{liao2021,goldberg2018}.\\
    %------------------------------------------------------------------
      \\
       \realinterestrate
       &  Real interest rate (\%) 
       &  WDI
       & \citet{liao2021,goldberg2018}\\
      %------------------------------------------------------------------------
     \inflation
     &  Inflation (annual \%) 
     & WDI 
     & \citet{forbes2012}\\     
    %-----------------------------------------------------------------
       \\
    \tradeopen 
   &  Volume of imports plus exports (\% of GDP) 
    &  World Development Indicators - World Bank, Available at: 
\url{http://www.atopdata.org/data.html}
    & \citet{fernandez2016}.\\
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \kai 
     & Overall inflow restrictions index  
     & all asset categories
     & \citet{fernandez2016}.\\
     %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     \\
      \kao 
       & Overall outflow restrictions index 
       & all asset categories
       & \citet{fernandez2016}.\\
      %---------------------------------------------------------------------
      \\
      \\
      \EXR 
     & 1 to 5, the higher, the more flexible 
     & IMF Annual Report on Exchange Arrangements and Exchange Restrictions (AREAER) and Coarse Classification Exchange Rate Regime, Available at: \url{http://www.carmenreinhart.com/data/browse-bytopic/topics/11/}
   &\citet{chinn2006,ilzetzki2019}\\
     %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \\
     \peglag
       & Exchange rate peg 1 = Yes, 0 = No. 
       & all asset categories
       &\citet{shambaugh2004,liao2021}.\\
       \bottomrule
       \end{tblr}
       \end{table}

     %-------------------------------------------------------------
     %  BIBLIOGRAPHY
     %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

     \bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}
       \bibliography{JIMF_FEM}
       \end{document}
```

my output:

[image]

[image]

Comment: In `colspec` you defined only 3 colums and `tblr` does not use `@{}`, it has specific options for column separator settings.

Comment: Off-topic: (a) Why is there both `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` and `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`? Pls delete the former. (b) Why do you load both `enumerate` and `enumitem`? I suggest loading only the latter. (c) Why are the macros `\RealGDPpercapita` etc defined as being of type `mathop`?! Give `\newcommand{\RealGDPpercapita}{\textsc{RGDPpercap}}` etc a try. Better yet, don't define dozens of macros that all do the same thing. Instead, define a *single* macro `\newcommand\vn[1]{\textsc{#1}}`, where "vn" is short for "variable name", and then write `\vn{RealGDPpercapita}`, `\vn{vix}`, etc.

Comment: @mico , Thanks for pointing out my mistake, I have removed unnecessary package accordingly and changed to:  \newcommand\vn[1]{\textsc{#1}} then  \vn{RealGDPpercapita} ; \vn{GDPconst} ;  \vn{GDPgrowth} ;  \vn{realinterestrate};  \vn{inflation} ; \vn{tradeopen} ; \vn{kai} ; \vn{kao} ; \vn{meanportfoliovol} ;  \vn{peglag} ;   \vn{kaopen} ; \vn{EXR} ; \vn{vix}; \vn{MThree}; \vn{Fed}; \vn{Shadow};  \vn{Trade} meanwhile i still don't find how to arrange the citation in last column

Comment: As user @CarLaTeX has already pointed out, you need to rethink the organization of the `tblr` environment. Why do you specify only 3 columns when there should be 4?

Comment: @CarLaTeX can you explain  more please or make modifications  in the code please 

Comment: @user169906 See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to clean a bit your code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,a4paper]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{enumitem}                    
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\tc[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\usepackage[font={bf},skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption} 
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{microtype}  % new
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, varwidth}
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}
\newcommand\vn[1]{\textsc{#1}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[nospace]{varioref}  
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref} 
\crefname{equation}{eq.}{eq.}
%---------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%------------------------------------------------
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Appendix}\label{tab:addlabel}                              
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={lX[1,j]X[1.2,j]X[j]},
    column{1}={leftsep=0pt,cmd=\vn},
    row{1}={font=\bfseries, c, m, cmd=},
    column{Z}={rightsep=0pt},
    rows={rowsep=4pt},
    }
% table preamble
\toprule
Symbol 
&   Variable Description
&   Source                       
&   Related Literature                       \\
% table body
\midrule
\SetCell[c=4]{c, font=\itshape, cmd=}     Push factors 
&   &                                   \\
\midrule    
M3
& M3 for the United States, National Currency, Monthly, Seasonally Adjusted        
&  Available at: \url{https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/MABMM301USA657S}
& \citet{Belke2019,BIS2017} \\
Fed 
& Effective Federal Funds Rate. In percentage points, end of the period, monthly.
&IMF International Financial Statistics and Fed. Reserve Bank of St. Louis (2021b) 
Available at: \url{https://www.federalreserve.gov/monetarypolicy.htm}
& \citet{Belke2019,BIS2017}                             \\      
Shadow 
&US shadow rate from Federal Reserve Bank of Atlanta
& Haver Analytics 
& \citet{wu2016,liao2021}\\

%------------------------------------------------------------------     
\midrule
\SetCell[c=4]{c, font=\itshape,cmd=}     Pull factors
&   &                                   \\
\midrule

RealGDPpercap
& Real GDP per capita (log)
&  WDI 
& \citet{liao2021,goldberg2018}.\\
%---------------------------------------------------------------------
GDPG
& GDP growth (annual \%)
&  WDI  
&\citet{liao2021,goldberg2018}.\\
%------------------------------------------------------------------
RealRate
&  Real interest rate (\%) 
&  WDI
& \citet{liao2021,goldberg2018}\\
%------------------------------------------------------------------------
Infl
&  Inflation (annual \%) 
& WDI 
& \citet{forbes2012}\\     
%-----------------------------------------------------------------
TradeOpen 
&  Volume of imports plus exports (\% of GDP) 
&  World Development Indicators - World Bank, Available at: 
\url{http://www.atopdata.org/data.html}
& \citet{fernandez2016}.\\
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
KAI 
& Overall inflow restrictions index  
& all asset categories
& \citet{fernandez2016}.\\
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
KAO 
& Overall outflow restrictions index 
& all asset categories
& \citet{fernandez2016}.\\
%---------------------------------------------------------------------
EXR 
& 1 to 5, the higher, the more flexible 
& IMF Annual Report on Exchange Arrangements and Exchange Restrictions (AREAER) and Coarse Classification Exchange Rate Regime, Available at: \url{http://www.carmenreinhart.com/data/browse-bytopic/topics/11/}
&\citet{chinn2006,ilzetzki2019}\\
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Peg
& Exchange rate peg 1 = Yes, 0 = No. 
& all asset categories
&\citet{shambaugh2004,liao2021}.\\
\bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
%-------------------------------------------------------------
%  BIBLIOGRAPHY
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}
\bibliography{JIMF_FEM}
\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

Since you didn't attach your bibitems I used these:

```
@article{Belke2019,
  title={Flows to emerging market and developing economies--global liquidity and uncertainty versus country-specific pull factors},
  author={Belke, Ansgar and Volz, Ulrich},
  journal={Review of development finance},
  volume={9},
  number={1},
  pages={32--50},
  year={2019},
  publisher={Africagrowth Institute}
}
@article{BIS2017,
  title={Global liquidity indicators},
  journal={Bank for Interantional Settlement},
  author={{BIS}},
  year={2017}
}
@article{wu2016,
  title={Measuring the macroeconomic impact of monetary policy at the zero lower bound},
  author={Wu, Jing Cynthia and Xia, Fan Dora},
  journal={Journal of Money, Credit and Banking},
  volume={48},
  number={2-3},
  pages={253--291},
  year={2016},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}
@article{liao2021,
  title={Closing time: Reputational constraints on capital account policy in emerging markets},
  author={Liao, Steven and McDowell, Daniel},
  journal={The review of international organizations},
  pages={1--26},
  year={2021},
  publisher={Springer}
}
@article{fernandez2016,
  title={Capital control measures: A new dataset},
  author={Fern{\'a}ndez, Andr{\'e}s and Klein, Michael W and Rebucci, Alessandro and Schindler, Martin and Uribe, Martin},
  journal={IMF Economic Review},
  volume={64},
  pages={548--574},
  year={2016},
  publisher={Springer}
}
@article{chinn2006,
  title={What matters for financial development? Capital controls, institutions, and interactions},
  author={Chinn, Menzie D and Ito, Hiro},
  journal={Journal of development economics},
  volume={81},
  number={1},
  pages={163--192},
  year={2006},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
@article{shambaugh2004,
  title={The effect of fixed exchange rates on monetary policy},
  author={Shambaugh, Jay C},
  journal={the Quarterly Journal of economics},
  volume={119},
  number={1},
  pages={301--352},
  year={2004},
  publisher={MIT Press}
}
@techreport{goldberg2018,
  title={International capital flow pressures},
  author={Goldberg, Linda S and Krogstrup, Signe},
  year={2018},
  institution={National Bureau of Economic Research}
}
@article{forbes2012,
  title={Capital flow waves: Surges, stops, flight, and retrenchment},
  author={Forbes, Kristin J and Warnock, Francis E},
  journal={Journal of international economics},
  volume={88},
  number={2},
  pages={235--251},
  year={2012},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
@article{ilzetzki2019,
  title={Exchange arrangements entering the twenty-first century: Which anchor will hold?},
  author={Ilzetzki, Ethan and Reinhart, Carmen M and Rogoff, Kenneth S},
  journal={The Quarterly Journal of Economics},
  volume={134},
  number={2},
  pages={599--646},
  year={2019},
  publisher={Oxford University Press}
}
```

Comment: I do so appreciate your professionalism, thank you for taking the time to look for bibitems , My thanks, and appreciation.

Comment: @user169906 You're welcome. Next time please remember to add them to your question.